# Photon Engine Native OSX cpp SDK 4.1.5

Tags: c++, macos, networking, multiplayer, photon

I wanted to test custom type support with Photon Engine so I downloaded the 4.1.5 native cpp OSX sdk and built demo_typeSupport.

Unfortunately the demo crashes inside the lib as soon as a second player joins the room and data starts being exchanged.

The same demo (from the native Windows sdk) works just fine on my Windows rig.

I'm running OSX 10.10.4 and Xcode 7.0.1, has anybody been able to successfully run demo_typeSupport using the native cpp OSX sdk?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the current release. It will be fixed in 4.1.5.1.